# If old MBR is used and there are already 3 primary partitions, how can I create two more partitions with "parted"?

Tags: parted

Using a RHEL7 machine, without GPT, I can see 3 primary partitions on a disk. The disk still has free space in the end.

**Question**:

How can I create 2 more partitions, a 512 MByte one, and a 1 GByte one? The last partition is at ex.: 13.7G ?

If I create a primary partiton, then I cannot create any more.

If I create an extended partition, I'm only allowed to create "logical" (?) partitions, but they are created with 1 KByte size!

If I try to create a "logical" partition when there is only 3 primary partitons, it doesn't allows me to do it, only primary and extended is allowed.

I suspect that I should create an extended partition, using all remaining disk space as the fourth one, and somehow, I have to create 2 partitions inside that extended partition so sum I will have my 3+2 partitions that I can use later. But how to do this using `parted`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `print` your partition table in `parted` to see the disk size and available space, then

```
mkpart extended 14029 15564
```

will create an extended partition starting at 14029MB and ending at 15564MB (adjust both values to suit — I'm basing these on your 13.7GB and 1.5GB figures), and

```
mkpart logical 14030 14542
```

will create a 512MB logical partition inside the extended partition, and finally

```
mkpart logical 14543 15564
```

will create a ~1GB logical partition filling up the rest of the extended partition.

(You should make sure your extended partition takes up all the available remaining space.)

Comment: how many logical can I have this way? Many thanks! :)

Comment: You can have as many logical partitions as disk space allows (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_boot_record) for details).